# EmberJS doesn't render component/helper and no error messages in console dev tools

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

so this is my hbs tpl

```
{{#collection- value=(get game prop) field=value.field as |col|}}
            {{#number-format isNumber=(eq value.type 'number') value=col as |val|}}
              {{#if value.linkable}}
                {{#link-to value.linkable.route (get game value.linkable.paramField)}}
                  {{value.prefix}}
                  {{val}}
                {{/link-to}}
              {{else if (eq value.type 'date')}}
                {{debugger}}
                {{format-date '2015-06-25 16:09:23'}}

              {{else}}
                {{value.prefix}}
                {{val}}
              {{/if}}
            {{/number-format}}
          {{/collection-}}
```

the problem is on line **{{format-date '2015-06-25 16:09:23'}}** which stops execution here, and I see no errors whatsoever in chrome dev tools console. The {{debugger}} has no effect before this line, so it's somewhere else which may conflict with my older helper file, but I got it removed completely from app/helpers folder.

Before that I had a custom helper written myself with the same name, which I then deleted and installed the following lib

https://chrishonniball.github.io/ember-string-helpers/

All other methods of the **ember-string-helpers** are working except for **format-date**

Any ideas why?

Also how to enable debugging (logging to understand what's the cause of the problem)? Right now it's total silence
[image]

Comment: Is there any chance for condition failing for  `else if (eq value.type 'date')` so that `else if` block is not at all executed. if you got doubt with `{{format-date` helper then you can check this helper with first if block or above so that you can confirm is there any collision with `{{format-date`

Comment: It doesn't work specifically to this tag, if I insert **{{uc-words 'hello world'}}** for example - it all works. Just that format-date that fails template to load with no errors.

Comment: may be try removing `tmp` folder and restart ember server that might help.

Comment: tried - didn't help, no effect

Comment: @DmitrySemenov: Did you remove the `dist` folder as well?